# Serializer not found

Tags: scala, playframework

I am currently doing a Play tutorial. I have defined a controller `Event` like this:

```
package controllers

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

import com.semisafe.ticketoverlords.Event

class Event extends Controller{

  def list = Action { request =>
    val events: Seq[Event] = ???
    Ok(Json.toJson(events))
  }
}
```

Then, in the package `com.semisafe.ticketoverlords`, I defined the corresponding `object` and `case class`:

```
package com.semisafe.ticketoverlords

import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Format}

case class Event(
  id: Long,
  name: String,
  start: DateTime,
  end: DateTime,
  address: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  country: String
)


object Event {
  implicit val format: Format[Event] = Json.format[Event]
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
No Json serializer found for type Seq[controllers.Event]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

On the line:

```
Ok(Json.toJson(events))
```

But this should not be the case, because I have defined a formatter and I am importing the class which contains that formatter.

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implicit formatter doesn't seem to be visible to the piece of code that needs it. I am not sure the `Event` class in you `Controller` is the one you think: it might be a reference to the controller itself, as it is also named `Event`. Try to rename your `Controller` to something like `EventController` and import the implicit formatter if needed.

Comment: Yes, it was a name clash.